# How to "think in React" for this complex example?

Tags: jquery, meteor, reactjs

Apologies in advance that this is probably not a one right solution type of question but I don't know how to break it down into more simple parts or where else to ask it.

I'm having some trouble bridging the gap between the more trivial react samples/demos available online and how to "think in react" for more complex apps.

I have a pre-existing solution to something built with Meteor and a bunch of jquery. It's a bit hacky and I think would be a good candidate to refactor with React if I can figure out how.

It looks like this:

### [image]

If I start by [breaking it down into a component hierarchy](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy) I get something like the following:

[image]

- Purple - A user editable HTML content container. Users can edit any of the html within the container via a WYSIWYG editor.
- Yellow - Within the html container each top level block of html... p's, lists, img's are given unique Ids - because of the WYSIWYG editor these might not be capable of being sub-components of Purle
- Green - Markers are rendered but initially invisible for every block. Hovering over a block or over a marker reveals the marker associated with the block. Clicking the marker starts the process of adding an Action. If a block already has a thread attached to it, the marker+count is rendered right away (as per the marker with 1 in it). The markers are all contained within Red
- Sea-foam green - Actions are what is added when the marker is clicked and thread saved
- Blue - container for all of it, calling it an Entry for lack of a better name

Now here is where my ability to think in react falls apart. Each component seems to have pretty severe inter-dependencies with the other components.

The markers seem like they would be best as their own component but their state is controlled more by other components than internally.

- Editing the HTML content is done with an editor that depends on all of the HTML in the container being one string so the blocks can't really be broken into separate components.
- Hovering over the content blocks displays/hides markers so events on the content area impacts the state of the markers components. The events are at the HTML block level despite those not necessarily being individual components
- The existence of each marker is strictly related to the number of content blocks in the content HTML area
- Whether each marker has an Action associated with it is strictly related to the Actions collection
- Correct positioning of the markers depends on how the content is rendered and/or re-sized
- Clicking a marker changes the state of the Action component, while the inverse is true as well, (cancelling/deleting and Action changes the state of a marker).

How would you work through "thinking in react" with an example of this complexity? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a read through your example and I'm not entirely sure how it works, so I'm going just going try and answer your question generally and throw in some specific examples from your example application.

> Now here is where my ability to think in react falls apart. Each component seems to have pretty severe inter-dependencies with the other components.

So to the basic concept in react is to keep stuff as props as much as possible, and if you have state that needs to be shared by multiple components, you need to abstract the state to a parent (or grand parent) that is above them. If they don't have appropriate parent to bridge that gap, you can create another component that holds this state and has both of them as children. If the tree you're creating is too large, this is where flux comes in to solve some of these problems, but I won't talk about this here since it's probably easier to just so things with React and learn it from there until you experience the pain points.

For example if the turquoise Action/Thread component is affected by clicks on the markers, you would need a parent that holds the state above them.

> The markers seem like they would be best as their own component but their state is controlled more by other components than internally.

They should be their own component for sure and probably a child component of the text block. The text component will take a prop that will allow it to determine whether those blocks are shown or not.

**General Advice**

I think generally the easiest way to try and model this is to start from the bottom and gradually work your way up. Start with everything static and with everything as props, when you start to need interactions you can start applying state and gradually move that state up as you build out your components and turning the 'state' in the child components into props. Only then do I think will it start to become clear where your state needs to be.

**Some Pseudo Code**

I wrote some pseudo Javascript code to visual how I would start to structure this part of your app. It won't do anything but hopefully it will help you visualise what I mean. If you follow it from `ParentWithState` and work your way through the render functions up towards the child `Marker` hopefully you'll see what i mean.

```
var Marker = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="marker" onClick={this.props.handleMarkerEvent}>
        +
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var TextBlock = React.createClass({
  var markerData = this.props.markerData;
  var marker = null;

  //do some logic with markerData

  if(markerData.show === true){
    marker = <Marker handleMarkerEvent={this.props.handleMarkerEvent}>
  }

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="textBlock">
        {this.text}
        {marker}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Actions = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    <div className="actions">
      //some code to display the actions
    </div>
  }
})

var ParentWithState = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      textBlockData: [
        //textBlock data objects
      ],
      //put all the data you need for the app here 
    }
  },

  handleMarkerEvent: function(){
    //do some stuff when marker is clicked
    //change state which will propagate down
  },

  render: function() {
    var textBlocks = this.state.textBlockData.map(function(textBlock){
      return (
        <TextBlock text={textBlock.text} markerData={textBlock.markerData} markerEvent={this.handleMarkerEvent}>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="text-blocks">
          {textBlocks}
        </div>
        <Actions />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

The last thing I'll mention here, since the `Marker` component has a function that affects the state at its grandparent, I'll make the event handler at the `ParentWithState` component and then pass it down as a prop, then finally in the child I'll call it using the `onClick` handler, but actually its the parent that controls this function

Comment: Fantastic answer! The key statement IMO is "you have state that needs to be shared by multiple components, you need to abstract the state to a parent (or grand parent) that is above them" (in this case, the `Entry` component, although if there are multiple entries that state may be managed by a component even higher up the tree). To manipulate that data, the parent that owns the state should pass function references into the children, which the children call when necessary. This pattern is the key to "thinking in react."

Comment: I think the general way you answered this is the best way it could have been answered. Great answer and thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, hope you manage to figure your way through it! I'd love to see how it turns out as I've worked with both Meteor and React, but never put them both together.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create global state and use it to render all your components. It looks like you are missing Flux to get things done.